# Can't open Fern Wifi Crack in GUI

Tags: wireless, software-installation, python, 18.04

```
root@DeVampz:~/Downloads/fern-wifi-cracker-master/Fern-Wifi-Cracker# python execute.py
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x149
```

Executing Fern Wifi Cracker by executing `python execute.py` as `root` gave me a weird appearance. I can't use it.

[Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7qGW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [this link](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/issues/66), there is a workaround to run QT apps when you encountering this issue. Try adding `QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1` after `sudo` and before `python`:

```
sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 python execute.py
```